# How to host a React App on Github gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I'm having problems getting a basic React app so it appears as a Github page, it seems to be always falling on a set of instructions instead. I've been attempting to resolve this issue for the passed 3days, no matter what documentation I read and steps I follow it seems to give always the same result.
The best set of instructions I've found so far are :https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/deploying-github-pages-with-create-react-app

You'll find the repo here:
https://github.com/guillaumelauzier/my-app

And app page here:
https://guillaumelauzier.github.io/my-app/

What am I doing rong? All seem to be working well on my localhost by doing `npm start`, I pushed all files using the following command:

```
echo "# my-app" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:guillaumelauzier/my-app.git
git push -u origin master
```

All stackoverflow posts I read on React app hosted on GH-Pages don't seem to bring a conclusive solution. Would greatly appreciate help on this as I need to get this up and running by monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through https://pages.github.com/ and found that you need to set the folder for your `index.html` file from github repository setting.

Hope this helps: https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this help clarify the changes I need to make. Thought I can't seem to be able to add any other source pages aside from ''master branch'' and ''none''.

Comment: yes, it seems you will need a docs folder, which will contain ur index.html file. Let me know if that works.